# console.log outputs 'function <valueOf result> ' instead of '<valueOf result>'

Tags: javascript, function, google-chrome, console

I am reading the javascript manual and I have wtote following code:

```
//sum
function sum(arg1) {
    var sum = arg1;

    function f(arg2) {
        sum += arg2;
        return f;
    };

    f.valueOf = function () {
        return sum;
    };

    f.toString = function () {
        return sum;
    };

    return f;
}
```

and I execute it like this:

```
console.log(sum(1)(2)(3)(4));
```

According the manual `console.log` should output the result of `valueOf` function

but it output

```
function 10
```

please explain this behaviour.

Comment: do you mean the word function in the output? it could be the beaviour of the console.

Comment: @Nina Scholz yes, I am about this behaviour

Comment: `but it output function 10` - not in my browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> According the manual console.log should output the result of valueOf function

I don't know what "manual" you're talking about, but in general, `console.log` *doesn't* call `valueOf` on what you output. The implementations of `console.log` vary from JavaScript engine to JavaScript engine, but in general they try to give you more useful information than calling `valueOf` would.

If you want to trigger `valueOf`, you'll need to do that intentionally, for instance:

```
console.log(sum(1)(2)(3)(4).valueOf());
// ------------------------^^^^^^^^^^
```

or (since your function is designed to produce a number):

```
console.log(+sum(1)(2)(3)(4));
// ---------^
```

Example:

```js
function sum(arg1) {
    var sum = arg1;

    function f(arg2) {
        sum += arg2;
        return f;
    };

    f.valueOf = function () {
        return sum;
    };

    f.toString = function () {
        return sum;
    };

    return f;
}

console.log(sum(1)(2)(3)(4).valueOf());
// ------------------------^^^^^^^^^^

console.log(+sum(1)(2)(3)(4));
// ---------^
```

```html
Look in the actual browser console; the Stack Snippets console doesn't quite do what the real browser console does.
```

Comment: with + all works properly, but I am not sure which object can I return to get this behaviour

Comment: where did you get the idea of adding a + sign on the start of it? can you link it or explain. thanks :D

Comment: @Semi-Friends + means cast to number

Comment: @Semi-Friends http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133770/how-do-i-convert-a-string-into-an-integer-in-javascript

Comment: @gstackoverflow: I'm sorry, I don't know what you mean by *"but I am not sure which object can I return to get this behaviour"*.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, please provide code which approximately equals code in engine

Comment: @gstackoverflow: Again, I have no idea what you mean by that. The above does what you said you want it to do. You need to do *something* with the returned function that invokes `valueOf`, otherwise it's a reference to the function (which your code relies on when calling it with `(2)`).